# Info Window for Google Maps

Tags: android, infowindow

I'm searching for a easy way to create Info-Windows for Google-Maps in Android. 
For example: a function with longitude, latitude and text parrameters. These were show onclick a location on the map.

Thanks for help

Comment: you can use [this](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/google-map-example-in-android-with-info.html) concept also.

Comment: Thanks but this is as beautiful as [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)